# Node.js: Copy Functions and Variables to another script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to javascript (and to this website) so please bear with me. I am using Node.js, and I am trying to make a Minecraft bot. I am using a module/plugin system to keep my scripts organized and easy to modify. I cannot figure out how to copy the variables and functions over from the script that starts the modules/plugins.

Here is the script the initializes the modules:

```
////Start libraries
console.log("Starting libraries...")
var mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
var navigatePlugin = require('mineflayer-navigate')(mineflayer);
var scaffoldPlugin = require('mineflayer-scaffold')(mineflayer);
var blockFinderPlugin = require('mineflayer-blockfinder')(mineflayer);
var requireIndex = require('requireindex');
var path = require('path')
var childProcess = require('child_process');
console.log("Done!")

////Create Bot
console.log("Starting bot...")
var bot = mineflayer.createBot({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 25565,
  username: CENSORED,
  password: CENSORED,
  verbose: true,
});
console.log("Done!")

////Start Libraries
navigatePlugin(bot);
scaffoldPlugin(bot);
blockFinderPlugin(bot);

////Start Plugins
var plugins = requireIndex(path.join(__dirname, 'Plugins'));
```

And here is one of the module scripts:

```
console.log("Chat log plugin started.")

////Log chat to console
bot.on('whisper', function(username, message) {
  console.log(username + " whispers to you: " + message)
});

bot.on('chat', function(username, message) {
  console.log(username + ": " + message)
});
```

Comment: Do it the same way as the other plugins. Note that they are functions that get passed `bot` (`navigatePlugin(bot);`). Have a look at the code of those plugins.

Comment: There are no other plugins.

Comment: I assumed `mineflayer-navigate` is a plugin since you called the variable `navigatePlugin`. It doesn't matter how you call it though, that would be the way to do it. Look at that code.

Comment: Wait i need bot and the mineflayer functions from the main script to use in the module script.